# AVAudioPlayer play/pause/stop and UIViewController release/dealloc

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer instance attached with a view controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *previewAudioPlayer;
```

I initialized it in `-viewDidLoad`.

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioPlayer *aNewPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
self.previewAudioPlayer = aNewPlayer;
[aNewPlayer release];

[self.previewAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

And, i release it in the view controllers `-dealloc` method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_previewAudioPlayer pause];
    [_previewAudioPlayer release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Audio is played on a button click.

```
[self.previewAudioPlayer play];
```

Now, if the view controller is dismissed or pop'ed, dealloc should be called and audio player should stop and view controller should be destroyed. However, this doesn't happen. The audio doesn't stop, because the dealloc is not called until the audio stops playing. What's going on here? And, how can i make sure that if user is dismissing the controller than the audio stops.

Comment: Have you know how to play continues audio after destroyed that ViewController on we have created instance of AVPlayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pause or stop the audio when the view gets dismissed, that is when the `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` methods get called.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [_previewAudioPlayer stop];
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, however i'm still looking for the answer to "Why isn't the dealloc method gets called". Thanks.

Comment: Have you know how to play continues audio after destroyed that ViewController on we have created instance of AVPlayer.

Comment: You'll probably have to keep the `AVAudioPlayer` instance alive somehow. If the view controller is the owner, when it dies, so it will the player.